# Windows RDP quality deteriorates with time until a full Windows client restart

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

When I connect with RDP from Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Windows Server 2012, in the beginning the connection is flying, but after half-a-day, it becomes sluggish and with a lag of a second-two.

Closing all the applications and reopening the connection doesn't help.

However if I restart the client machine which I use connect (Windows 8.1), the connection is good again.

Is this a known issue? And is there any solution besides restart?

Comment: From what I've seen RDP versions 6.2 and higher do have some problem.
You can try coping the mstsc.exe, mstscax.dll, mstscax.dll.mui from a Win7 installation (without the updated RDP), and run them from your Win8.1 machine.

Comment: What is the version of mstsc.exe on your client? Have you enabled RDP 8.0 on the server? If so, UDP transport as well? Are the client and server located on same network/subnet? If not, how are they connected?